# parse xml with php simplexml

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)
>   [PHP SimpleXML Namespace Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027398/php-simplexml-namespace-problem)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$str = <<<ETO
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:bc="http://www.brightcove.tv/link" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Press Conference with Chairman of the FOMC, Ben S. Bernanke</title>
            <link>http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid720309829001/bctid1414417812001?src=mrss</link>
            <description>Chairman of the FOMC, Ben S. Bernanke, Washington, D.C.</description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 26 Jan 2012 11:57:19 -0800</pubDate>
            <media:player height="580" url="http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid720309829001/bctid1414417812001?src=mrss" width="440"/>
            <media:thumbnail height="90" url="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d20/unsecured/media/66043936001/66043936001_1414432575001_fomc-presser-thumb.jpg?pubId=66043936001" width="120"/>
            <media:thumbnail height="360" url="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d20/unsecured/media/66043936001/66043936001_1414432069001_fomc-presser-large.jpg?pubId=66043936001" width="480"/>
            <bc:duration>4016</bc:duration>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Press Conference with Chairman of the FOMC, Ben S. Bernanke</title>
            <link>http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid720309829001/bctid1258170578001?src=mrss</link>
            <description>Chairman of the FOMC, Ben S. Bernanke, Washington, D.C.</description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 26 Jan 2012 08:21:02 -0800</pubDate>
            <media:player height="580" url="http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid720309829001/bctid1258170578001?src=mrss" width="440"/>
            <media:thumbnail height="90" url="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d16/unsecured/media/66043936001/66043936001_1014046968001_DSC-95132.jpg?pubId=66043936001" width="120"/>
            <media:thumbnail height="360" url="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d16/unsecured/media/66043936001/66043936001_1014127979001_DSC-95132.jpg?pubId=66043936001" width="480"/>
            <bc:duration>2897</bc:duration>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
ETO;
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xmlObj->channel->item as $item){
    echo $item->title.'<br />';
    echo $item->link.'<br />';
    echo $item->description.'<br />';
    echo $item->pubDate.'<br />';
    echo $item->xpath('media:player').'<br />';
    echo $item->xpath('media:thumbnail',0)->url.'<br />';
    echo $item->xpath('media:thumbnail',1)->url.'<br />';
    echo $item->xpath('bc:duration').'<br />';
    echo '<hr />';
}
?>
```

How to parse some node like `media:player`,`media:thumbnail`, `bc:duration`? I met some wrong, 2 string array and 2 wrong...

```
Array
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in E:\www\1.php on line 37 
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in E:\www\1.php on line 39 
Array
```

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899747/php-simplexml-issue

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991832/php-accessing-namespaced-xml-with-simplexml

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517887/php-parsing-a-georss-namespace-with-simplexml

Comment: OMG~~ too many duplicate, why I can not search them? thanks.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858136/accessing-namespace-colon-nodes-in-xml-with-simplexml-php

Comment: Heh, for some reason, a _lot_ of people can't seem to do it ;) To be fair, knowing it is called a 'namespace' does help a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you, what you want:

```
$hlp = $item->xpath('media:thumbnail[1]');
echo $hlp[0]['url'];
```

Maybe, there are better methods...I'll see, if I can find some.

Regarding the errormessage, ThinkingMonkey is right - you used the function incorrectly.

--

**edit:** This is probably a faster and more beautiful solution:

```
$media = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
$hlp = $media->player->attributes();
echo $hlp['url'].'<br />';
$hlp = $media->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
echo $hlp['url'].'<br />';
$hlp = $media->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
echo $hlp['url'].'<br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Most part of your code looks fine except for the use of function `xpath()`

From [SimpleXMLElement::xpath <sup>manual</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

```
public array SimpleXMLElement::xpath ( string $path )
```

It accepts only one parameter! you are passing 2 params:

```
echo $item->xpath('media:thumbnail',0)->url.'<br />';
echo $item->xpath('media:thumbnail',1)->url.'<br />';
```

You have used it correctly here!

```
echo $item->xpath('media:player').'<br />';
```

Just do this to access your `media:thumbnail`. Since, they will be parsed & stored as array:

```
echo $item->xpath('media:thumbnail[0]')->url.'<br />';
echo $item->xpath('media:thumbnail[1]')->url.'<br />';
```

Comment: `echo $item->xpath('media:player').'<br />';` return `array`, and how to make difference from 2 'media:thumbnail'? Thanks.